# OAuth with Bearer token and <a> tag

Tags: html, oauth-2.0, authorization, bearer-token

We are currently thinking about using OAuth2 for Authorization.

Is there a possibility to send the Bearer token when clicking on an anchor tag?

Comment: See the solution by @Taiseer Joudeh
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533722/validate-oauth-bearer-token-with-form-post?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

One of option I can provide is to save the bearer token into session storage. I'd like see if other guys have better solutions.