# Validate OAuth bearer token with form post

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I've created a OData based web back-end using Web API 2.  This works really well, using AuthorizeAttribute on controllers.

I'd like to be able to upload a files, via a standard html form and a submit.

We are passing the OAuth token, which would normally be passed in the header of an OData request, as a hidden input field.

Question: How do you validate this in the controller?

Comment: You want to validate the token inside a controller already attribute with [Authorize]? Sorry can't understand the question.

Comment: No. The token isn't passed in the header, as it normally would, but a hidden field. [Authorize] can't be on the controller for a standard form using a standard submit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you need to un-protect the token, then from the "ticket" you check if there is principal and if it is authenticated (check property IsAuthenticated). Use the code below inside your controller:

```
string token = "Your token goes here";
Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket ticket = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(token);
```

Comment: Thank you! Much simpler than I was anticipating.

Comment: The Unprotect function will return expired tokens, so you will also want to make sure the token is not expired, example: `ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc > DateTime.UtcNow`

Comment: Same issue I faced, here is my question which is related to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913508/generate-access-token-in-web-api-action-method-using-owin-and-iis-host